# How do you answer the question “who decides what is beautiful”?

Tags: questions

When answering “Qui décide ce qui est beau?”, do you use “I do” as in “je fais” or “oui” as in “yes”? Can you also answer with “je décide”?

Comment: *Je ne sais pas.* ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options. Usually you will use the emphatic pronoun *moi* (also called the disjonctif).

For example, you could say any of these depending on how verbose you want to be:

> Moi.
>
> C'est moi.
>
> C'est moi qui décide.

The emphatic pronouns are *je / **moi***, *tu / **toi***, *il / **lui***, *ils / **eux*** (*elle*, *nous*, *vous*, *elles* don't change).

You could also just use *je* but it would be less likely to appear without the emphatic *moi* :

> Moi, je décide.
>
> Je décide.

If you want to say something like "I do", you have to use *le* (literally "I do it"). This is true every time you want to replace a verb with "do". The same thing about *moi* applies here too.

> (Moi) je le fais.

You can't reply with just *oui* because this is an open-ended question, not a yes/no question. The following exchange makes no sense in either English or French.

> Qui décide ce qui est beau ? *Who decides what is beautiful?*
>
> Oui. *Yes.*